# Move 1 file from a directory in another directory depending on the time and date in python

Tags: python, sorting, compare

So i have 2 directories. In one directory there are multiple directories with multiple files. In another directory i have more files of only 1 extension. I need to write a script the goes through each and one of the subdirectories from the first directory, compares the modification date and time of 1 specific file in that subdirectory with the file form the second directory( the one i mentioned above) and then takes the file from the second directory and moves it into the subdirectory  where the file was compared .

I tried a lot of sorting and right now i am out of ideas

Comment: could you post what you have tried?

Comment: On which operating system shall this work?

Comment: It operates on OS

Answer (score 0):

.rglob() and os.path.getmtime() are probably the tools you're looking for. Here's an example script:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

# Change these variables as to match your directories:
INPUT_FOLDER = "./input"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "./output"

# Change .rglob("*") to desired suffix (for example .rglob("*.txt")):
paths_in_output = {output_path.name: output_path for output_path in Path(OUTPUT_FOLDER).rglob("*") if output_path.is_file()}

# Compares all files in input folder with files in output folder, 
# OVERWRITES file in output folder when file from input folder is modified more recently:
for input_path in Path(INPUT_FOLDER).glob("*"):
    if input_path.name in paths_in_output:
        output_path = paths_in_output[input_path.name]
        if os.path.getmtime(input_path) > os.path.getmtime(output_path):
            move(input_path, output_path)
```

**CAUTION:** Please be aware that this script DOES NOT make a backup of the old file when the newer file is moved to the Output Folder - the older file will be automatically overwritten.

This script can also have unexpected results if the subfolders in the output folder contain multiple files with the exact same file name (because of the dict comp that happens before the file comparisons, the script will only test the last file that it has found with the same name). If you foresee this happening, you could adapt the script accordingly: consider if you want to overwrite all older instances with a copy of the file from the input folder for example (you could use shutil.copy2() for this), or if you want to notify the user and let them decide how to proceed (I would personally prefer the last option).